# Scale a picture in a ScrollView with Autolayout

Tags: swift, image, swift2, height, scrollview

I have a scrollView with a picture inside, I want this picture to have the height of the scrollView (so we can only slide horizontally, not vertically). My UIViewController is using a lot of AutoLayout and I don't find a way to adapt the picture. I tried many things but AutoLayout seems disturbing.
Any idea how to do that please?

Here is a gif to show the problem :) http://gfycat.com/SnivelingUnlawfulGyrfalcon

Comment: The problem is that scrollView contentHeight will change to accommodate its subviews, to get a work around this I need to know more about what are you trying to achieve exactly.

Comment: Thanks for your comment ! I try to make the picture the same height as the scrollView so we can swipe only horizontally. (as you see in the gif)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution ! Here it is :
- the key is to use viewWillLayoutSubviews() in the ParentViewController
Here is the extract of my code :

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {

    imageViewVar.frame.size.height = scrollView.frame.height
    scrollView.contentSize = imageViewVar.frame.size
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    scrollView.delegate = self
    scrollView.addSubview(imageViewVar)
```